# How to store information in a list using a struct?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, visual-studio-2008, struct

I want to let the user create a new account for an application in Windows Form. I thought, it would be a good idea, to store all the related account information in a struct and use a list to store each account. Then, I would check each string inserted in the user name and password boxes (at the log in screen) and compare it with each string of every element on the list until it finds the right match (of user name and password)

What I have done so far:

```
    struct Birth
    {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    }
    struct accounts
    {
        char[] last_name;
        char[] first_name;
        char[] username;
        char[] password;
        int[] telephone_number;
        Birth birth_date;
    };
    List<accounts> utilizatori = new List<accounts>();
```

I have never worked with structs and lists at the same time before. How can I add a new element to the list in each field of the struct? Also, how can I save the information stored in the list so next time I open the project, I don't have to create the same account again?

Answer (score 1):

Read the technical guidelines of structs:

> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
>     (int, double, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx

Your use seems to violate the first three conditions.